# can we check multiple patterns using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

i want to check 2 patterns using regex.

can i check those both patterns in the same time (like if(condition1 | condition2) condition).

any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it exactly the way you did, with pipe separating the two+ expressions

For instance: The regular expresion `(abc)|(def)` would match `abc` OR `def`

Comment: That is the syntax. The regular expression `pattern1|pattern2` means "match pattern1 or pattern2".

Answer (score 4):

It really depends - namely, you can design your regex with "or" modifiers like this `"(match this)|(or this)"`. If you use carefully designed regex, you only need to do this:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex)
Matcher m = p1.matcher(searchstring)
```

Once. This is probably the most efficient way to go about things. The other option is to run two matcher/pattern object pairs, run `find` operations until `find` returns false than count the number of outputs. If they're both > 0 you're in business. The other option is if you only need one or more matches, to do:

```
if ( matcher1.find() & matcher2.find() )
{
    ...
}
```