# Regex pattern in java not updating

Tags: java, regex

I currently have the following:

```
  int noOfRPs = 3;

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("wifi_log")));

                // There are 3 RP's

                for (int RP = 0; RP < noOfRPs; ++RP){

                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                            String pattern = "^RP" + RP;
                            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                            if (m.find())
                                System.out.println("match = " + line);

                        }

                }

            }
            catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("IO Error, no file found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want to match the patterns: `RP0` then `RP1` and finally `RP2` in my text file. However at the moment, it is continuously matching `RP0` despite me changing the variable `pattern` on each run of the `for loop`...

Would anyone know what is happening here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the while loop RP doesn't change.

Comment: (1) You're compiling the regex for every *line* in the file, which doesn't make a lot of sense. (2) You iterate over the file lines... now you're at the end of the file. Now you increment RP, but you're still at the end of the file. (3) Are your loops inside-out? (4) Why not just compile three regexes and use each one?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your response. With regards to your second point, how could I fix this? I need to go over the file 3 times. The first time I am trying to extract lines with `RP0`.. the second time `RP1` and the third time `RP2`.

Comment: Without knowing details, I'd argue you only need to go over the file once, checking each line for RP0/RP1/RP2, and stuff them into an appropriate collection (i.e., one for each RPn).

Comment: @DaveNewton In this example I need to use 3 regexes... However, I could end up having to use upwards of 50. It seems odd to have to create 50 different regex patterns manually?

Comment: @Giri That was how *you* implemented it; we have no idea what your actual usecase is. If you're looking for `RPn` then write a regex for that, and figure out the number later. If you're looking for something else, then you need to be explicit about that--but that's not related to the current question.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the increment in `RP` (note, double-check variable conventions) is taking place one level above your `while` loop iteration.

A quick solution would be to invert the hierarchy of the loops, placing the `for` loop inside the `while` loop.

As such:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    for (int RP = 0; RP < noOfRPs; ++RP){
        String pattern = "^RP" + RP;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println("match = " + line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You read the file only on the first iteration of your `for` loop. On later iterations `br.readLine()` will return `null` immediately and there won't be any matching done.

One idea would be to merge your three patterns into a single pattern and match for all three subpatterns at the same time. To achieve this, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457185/can-we-check-multiple-patterns-using-regex-in-java). In short it is possible to use a pipe (`|`) to combine patterns.